# Django: edit existing object, but new on save

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In a blog-ish part of my django app, editing an existing entry results in creating a new entry.  It should modify the existing entry.

I have a simple model:

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

and a simple form for editing it:

```
class BlogEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
slug = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = BlogEntry
    fields = (..., 'slug')
```

and the view, somewhat simplified, is also straight-forward:

```
class BlogEditView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, slug=None):
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        if slug is None:
            print('Creating new entry.')
            context['entry'] = BlogEntryForm()
            context['entry'].publication_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', context)
        print('Using existing entry.')
        entry = get_object_or_404(BlogEntry, slug=slug)
        context['entry'] = BlogEntryForm(instance=entry)
        return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', context)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        blog_entry_form = BlogEntryForm(request.POST)
        if blog_entry_form.is_valid():
            blog_entry = blog_entry_form.save(commit=False)
            if blog_entry.slug is None or blog_entry.slug == '':
                print('New entry, slug is empty.')
                blog_entry.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
                blog_entry.slug = slugify(blog_entry.title) + '_' + hex(random.randint(0, 1e10))
            blog_entry.author = request.user
            blog_entry.save()
            return redirect(reverse('blog/article', args=[blog_entry.slug]))
        ...
```

In `get()`, I confirm with the print's that I am taking the correct branch.  If the entry exists, I set entry with the instance.  In `post()`, however, I always take the new entry branch.

The layout has the typical hidden element loop.

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }} hidden
{% endfor %}
```

though, suspiciously, when I look at the served html, I don't see the slug entry, so it's no surprise that it's not getting passed through.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to use the pk of the object, do you include that in your form? If not, add it as a hidden field.

Comment: I'm confused, the slug is unique, so I can fetch on slug as easily as on pk, no?  (ModelForm is just title, article_body, pub_date, and slug.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `slug` argument to the `post()` method as well.  This will allow you to get the blog entry to edit from the database and pass this entry to the form as an `instance` argument:

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
def post(self, request, slug=None):
    blog_entry = BlogEntry.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    blog_entry_form = BlogEntryForm(request.POST, instance=blog_entry)
    ...
```

**UPDATE**: To pass the `slug` argument to the `post()` method you should use the empty `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

In this case the form will be submitted to the url from which it was loaded.  So the `slug` argument for the POST request will be the same as for the GET.

Comment: Makes sense, but how do I get the form submission to cause slug to be sent as an arg?  I thought I needed to fetch such things from request, and request.POST in particular.

Comment: No, usual practice is to pass `pk`/`slug` of edited object in the url.  See updated answer.